# Bottom Sheet: Unresolved reference: fraction

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am facing problem here in `sheetState.progress.fraction`.

It was working fine, but now it is unresolved. don't know why?

```
Text(
   text = "Toggle Sheet fraction ${sheetState.progress.fraction}",
   color = Color.White
)
```

here is what I have been doing...

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
class BottomSheetActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyComposableTheme {
                val sheetState = rememberBottomSheetState(
                    initialValue = BottomSheetValue.Collapsed
                    ,animationSpec = SpringSpec(
                        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioHighBouncy
                    )
                )
                val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
                    bottomSheetState = sheetState
                )
                val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
                BottomSheetScaffold(
                    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
                    sheetContent = {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .height(300.dp),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                        ) {
                            Text(
                                text = "BottomSheet",
                                fontSize = 60.sp,
                                color = Color.White
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Black,
                    sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        Button(onClick = {
                            scope.launch {
                                if (sheetState.isCollapsed) {
                                    sheetState.expand()
                                } else {
                                    sheetState.collapse()
                                }
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text(
                                text = "Toggle Sheet fraction ${sheetState.progress.fraction}",
                                color = Color.White
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help me to resolve this problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sheetState.currentFraction to get the current fraction of the bottom sheet's position

**edit the code like this:**

```
Button(onClick = {
    scope.launch {
        if (sheetState.isCollapsed) {
            sheetState.expand()
        } else {
            sheetState.collapse()
        }
    }
}) {
    Text(
        text = "Toggle Sheet fraction ${sheetState.currentValue}",
        color = Color.White
    )
}
```

By using sheetState.currentFraction instead of sheetState.progress.fraction, you should be able to access the current fraction of the bottom sheet's position.

Comment: There is no method called `sheetState.currentFraction`. Please update or delete your question

Answer (score 2):

In the material3 version `androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.2` corresponding to the [BOM version](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom/bom-mapping)(23.10.01) you can create the state by the following code below

```kotlin
val offsetBottomSheet by remember(sheetState) {
    derivedStateOf {
        runCatching { sheetState.requireOffset() }.getOrDefault(0F)
    }
}
```

I have wrapped the `sheetState.requireOffset()` in `runCatching` as `requireOffset` will throw `IllegalStateException` when sheetConent has not been through a measurement pass